# Updating floating point number in animation

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate, fp

I'm trying to have an animated tikz graph with floating point values. While I can use floating point values as parameters for the graph, I can't seem to find a way to do so for displayed equations.  Below is a MWE using beamer. The green line is animated properly - but the parameter does not appear in simplified form.  The blue line shows the parameter appearing the way I would like it to (as a simplified number) but it is not updated in the tikz picture, even though it is updated outside that picture.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{step}   
\setcounter{step}{1}

\newcommand{\scalevalues}{ %
\FPmul{\scaled}{\thestep}{0.1}
\FPtrunc{\scaled}{\scaled}{1}
}

\scalevalues   
\scaled % will print 0.1 above picture

\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls, palindrome]{10}
\whiledo{\thestep < 21}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
    %
    \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[anchor=west]{\color{gray}x};
    \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[anchor=south]{\color{gray}y};
    % 
    \draw[-, thick, blue] (\scaled,-1) -- (5,4) node[anchor=east]{$\scaled x $};
    \draw[-, thick, green] (0.1*\thestep,-1) -- (2,3) node[anchor=east]{$0.1*\thestep x $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \stepcounter{step}
    \scalevalues  
    \scaled % will print updated values below picture
    \ifthenelse{\thestep < 21}{
            \newframe
    }{
        \end{animateinline}\relax 
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to carry out the calculation somehow but TikZ don't quite get that it's a computation it has to perform. So you can make it obvious by

```
{$\pgfmathparse{0.1*\thestep}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]\pgfmathresult x $}
```

in that node.

Comment: Wow, that was fast!  Thanks... I have to wait a few minutes until I can accept it.

Comment: @André No rush. Maybe someone else comes along with a better answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of building a loop around a parameterized `tikzpicture` inside the `animateinline` environment is to use the `\multiframe` command. This simplifies the code and saves you from possible pitfalls:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first, controls, palindrome]{10}
  \multiframe{21}{rNum=0.1+0.1}{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      %\useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (5,5);
      %
      \draw[->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[anchor=west]{\color{gray}x};
      \draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[anchor=south]{\color{gray}y};
      % 
      \draw[-, thick, blue] (\rNum,-1) -- (5,4) node[anchor=east]{$\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\rNum}x$};
      \draw[-, thick, green] (\rNum,-1) -- (2,3) node[anchor=east]{$\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\rNum}x$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}\relax 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please. In your answer, you use ..loop.. together ...palindrome...When I load it without ...loop.., it works fine also. Why?, palindrome is prioritised !!. If you cared, please tell me about ..poster...Here you use poster = first ? Why? I have read animate's document but now my english is bad to understand it....

Comment: It is not my code actually. I just improved it. Of course, palindrome and loop are mutually exclusive options. Take either the one or the other.

Comment: palindrome is prioritised compare with loop when the both are existed?

Comment: Maybe. To make it clear: It is an error to use both at the same time.

Comment: And about poster= first ? Can we use poster= last for this case?

Comment: Yes. `poster` can be set independently from any other option.

Comment: So, what is its effect? Still works fine if it is not appeared?

Comment: Please, have a look at the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf#subsection.6.1) .

Comment: Oh, sorry, seem I have asked too much...

Comment: No problem. But I think the manual is well written, if not fun to read ;-).